# How to check the transaction status if pending or execute using Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I am new to Jmeter. I'm working on the script where I have to cover following points. 
1. login with test user.
2. choose any test stock.
3. record transaction with that stock.
4. wait for 10 minutes for its success.
5. Check result (Success or Fail or pending).
6. send report email if unsuccessful

Here I'm able to write the script till the transaction is recorded. 
But I have to wait till it gets execute and check its status(pending,success,failure)

I have configured SMTP sampler also to send error email. But stuck at 4 and 5 point.
Can anyone please help how to achieve this using Jmeter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4. Add Test Action Sampler and configure it as follows:

   - Action: `pause`
   - Duration: `600000`

   It will pause the executing thread for 10 minutes
5. Add [Response Assertion](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) as a child of the request which does "Check Result" and configure it like:

   - Apply to: `Main sample and sub-samples`
   - Response field to test: `Text Response`
   - Pattern Matching Rules: `Contains`
   - tick `Not`
   - Add pattern `Fail`

   You might need to use different configuration depending on where comes the status and how does it exactly look like. The assertion will mark any sampler which doesn't contain `Fail` as successful and vice versa
6. Add [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) after step 5 and use `${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}` as Condition.
7. Add SMTP Sampler as a child of the If Controller